# Creating a pseudoterminal to make sudo happy

Tags: cloud, sudo, terminal

I need to automate the provisioning of a cloud instance (running Fedora 17) for which the following initial facts are true:

- I have ssh-key based access to a remote user (`cloud`)
- That user has password-free root access via `sudo`.

Manual configuration is as simple as logging in and running `sudo su -` and having at it, but I would like to fully automate this process.  The trick is that the system defaults to having the `requiretty` option enabled for `sudo`, which means that an attempt to do something like this:

```
ssh remotehost sudo yum -y install puppet
```

Will fail:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

I am working around this right now by first pushing over a small Python script that will run a command on a pseudoterminal:

```
import os
import sys
import errno
import subprocess

pid, master_fd = os.forkpty()

if pid == 0:
    # child process: now that we're attached to a
    # pty, run the given command.
    os.execvp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[1:])
else:
    while True:
        try:
            data = os.read(master_fd, 1024)
        except OSError, detail:
            if detail.errno == errno.EIO:
                break

        if not data:
            break

        sys.stdout.write(data)

    os.wait()
```

Assuming that this is named `pty`, I can then run:

```
ssh remotehost ./pty sudo yum -y install puppet
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there are solutions already available that I haven't considered.

- I would normally think about `expect`, but it's not installed by default on this system.
- `screen` can do this in a pinch, but the best I came up with was:

  ```
  screen -dmS sudo somecommand
  ```

  ...which does work but eats the output.

Are there any other tools available that will allocate a pseudoterminal for me that are going to be generally available?

Comment: Great question. I experimented a bit with `screen` a while back, but usually had to redirect the output elsewhere and `cat` it after the screen command had finished executing. The `-t` ssh option seems less hackish, though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `-t` option to [ssh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ssh.1.html#contenttoc2):

```
 -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute
         arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
         very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
         options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

You may need to use `-tt` if the script is going to be run non-interactively.

Comment: It was in fact the `-tt` I was missing.  I'm calling `ssh` via `pdsh`, and the connections don't have a local pty.  This really goes to reading comprehension on my part, I guess. Thanks for the pointer!